# How to handle .proto files outside of maven project directory (Useless Eclipse Warnings)

Tags: eclipse, maven, protocol-buffers

My project uses both Java and C++. Google Protocol Buffers are used for data exchange. All the .proto files are defined at the top level, then compiled into Java and C++ classes. My file system looks like

`/myProject
        /proto-share
        /java
        /cpp`

My Java projects use Maven. Everything builds correctly. My problem is that Eclipse is showing me a warning,

> Access "../../proto-share" directory is outside of project base directory

It does not like that my java pom.xml file invokes the **protobuf-maven-plugin** with a **protoSourceRoot** of **../../proto-share/**.

I can see why normally you would want an warning when your pom file uses files outside the project. You want to be sure your build is reproducible in the future. In this case though, I believe the best thing is to have all projects of various languages using a single source of proto files, rather than having the proto files copied multiple times down into the java and cpp directories.

I want to turn this warning off. Or I want to reorganize my project to use some best practice that eliminates the warning. Either way, I am tired of seeing this warning. I actually have multiple java maven projects and have many of these useless warnings that get in the way of me seeing legitimate warnings I need to address.

Any thoughts on how I can eliminate or hide this warning?

Comment: I tried using the maven-resource-plugin to copy the *.proto files into the project directory so that the protobuf-maven-plugin could have a proto path local to the project. This compiles fine but still produces the same warning in Eclipse.
I then tried adding the proto-share directory as another resource directory, thinking that might trick Maven into thinking its part of the project. Nope.

Comment: The most promising solution seems to be to create a project that just contains the proto files, then add a dependency on that project. protobuf-maven-plugin will compile any *.proto files it finds in projects yours is dependent on. This seems like overkill. I want projects to include only the needed *.proto files. Creating a project for all my permutations seems like a waste of time. Unless someone else has an idea, I will simply continue living with these warning messages.